# How to set the precision on a SAS numeric value

Tags: sas

I have this data set with 2 numeric values, these values are calculated by different systems with different precision parameters. So they round differently.

```
data test;
a = 10;
b= 11;
run;
```

Basically a and b started out as an almost same float value but due to rounding difference, ended up having a different value.
I need a proc sql which treats values like these as same (i,e. precision of (+/- 1);

So I need this to return true;

```
proc sql;
select * from test where a = b;
quit;
```

Comment: Did you try the ROUND() function?  You can use ROUND(x,1) to round to whole number. Or use ROUND(x,0.1) to round to tenths.

Comment: ROUND(10) = 10 ;round (11) = 11. So we are back to square one

Comment: Do you just mean `abs(a-b) <= 1` ?  Or to control for missing values `abs(a-b) between 0 and 1`.

Comment: Yes that will work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, and assumes you are saying that anything within the range of a single integer should be treated as the same value, then you could do something like:

```
where max(a,b) - min(a,b) le 1;
```

This assumes that there are no missing values.  If you have missing values you can use something like:

```
where max(sum(0,a),sum(0,b)) - min(sum(0,a),sum(0,b)) le 1;
```